# Why we are using _ in this expression str.replace(/[\W_]/g, '').toLowerCase(); We could have used /[\W]/g also but why are we using underscore?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

It is a javascript question.I was solving palindromes question on freecodecamp.Let me write the full code here:

```
 function palindrome(str) {
 var normalizedStr = str.replace(/[\W_]/g, '').toLowerCase();
 var reverseStr = normalizedStr.split('').reverse().join('');
  return normalizedStr === reverseStr;
 }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The **\W** metacharacter is used to find a non-word character. A word character is a character from a-z, A-Z, 0-9, **including the underscore** character. This means that if you use [\W] and not [\W_]

```
var normalizedStr = str.replace(/[\W]/g, '').toLowerCase();
```

your normalizedStr will still **contain underscore** after the replacement.

Because this challenge requires the removal of **all non-alphanumeric characters** (punctuation, spaces and symbols), it will return unwanted results for any processed strings that include "_":

> palindrome("_eye") -- should return true, but it will be false instead;
>
> palindrome("0_0 (: /-\ :) 0-0") -- should return true, but will be false instead;

Also, instead of converting the string to array, reverse it and convert it back to string before comparison, better use a **for loop to compare the arrays** for much better performance (especially if the string is bigger):

```
function palindrome(str) {
  var clearString = str.toLowerCase().replace(/[^0-9a-z]/gi, '').split('');
  
  for (var i = 0; i < clearString.length/2; i++) {
    if (clearString[i] !== clearString[clearString.length -1 -i]) {  
      return false;
    } 
  }
  return true;
}
```

Keep in mind that the **false** statement should be **first** and the **true** statement must be **outside the for loop**, otherwise it will break the function after the first match and return inaccurate result.

Benchmark snippet here:

```js
const stringLength = 100000;  // < < ADJUST THE STRING LENGTH HERE

const string = superString(stringLength);

console.log(`Random string length: ${string.length} symbols`);

benchMark(arraySplitReverseJoinMethod);
benchMark(forLoopComparisonMethod);

function arraySplitReverseJoinMethod(str) {
  return str == str.split('').reverse().join('');
}

function forLoopComparisonMethod(str) {
  let string = str.split('');
  
  for (var i = 0; i < string.length/2; i++) {
    if (string[i] !== string[string.length -1 -i]) {  
      return false;
    } 
  }

  return true;
}

function benchMark(func) {
  const start = +new Date();

  func(string);

  const end = +new Date();
  const total = end - start;

  console.log(`${func.name}: ${total} ms`);

  return `${func.name}: ${total} ms`;
}

function superString(n) {
  let superString = '';

  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    const randomString = Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 12);

    superString = superString.concat(randomString);
  }

  return superString;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure about the performance aspect? I was just doing this question as an interview prep and solved it with the for loop as you demonstrated, yet the answer in the post also pointed to the array-split-reverse-join method.

Comment: @CodeAt30, I am completely sure about this :) Why don't you test it with bigger strings yourself? Here is a demo: https://jsfiddle.net/bv4tjp15/6/

Comment: ha! 20x faster on my machine! So much for internet quizzes! in for loops we trust!

Answer (score 5):

`\W` match any non-word character `[^a-zA-Z0-9_]`

`_` the literal character `_`

so this regex will keep in your string only letters and numbers

Comment: "so this regex will keep in your string only letters and numbers" and " _ " this character also and \W negates the "_" , so we have to add this explicitly

Comment: Thanks a lot I got it.